# Flutter ,dart,The parameter 'colour' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

i dont know why i am getting the errors,i have previously coded the same and it worked perfectly fine maybe some new update or plugin please help me solve my error

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Color colour;
  final Function onPressed;
  RoundedButton({this.title, this.colour, @required this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      child: Material(
        elevation: 5.0,
        color: colour,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          minWidth: 200.0,
          height: 42.0,
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've updated your Dart SDK to a version which supports [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety). With null safety there are some differences to the way constructors work in Dart.

1. `@required` is now simply `required` - No @ symbol anymore.
2. If a property is not required, then it must have either a default value, or it must have a nullable type, e.g. `String?` or `Color?`.

Using default values, your code might look something like this:

```
final String title;
final Color colour;
final void Function() onPressed;

RoundedButton({
    this.title = "",
    this.colour = Colors.blue,
    required this.onPressed,
});
```

The rest of your class would be the same.

---

On the other hand, if you make the properties nullable, you might end up with something like this:

```
final String? title;
final Color? colour;
final void Function() onPressed;

RoundedButton({
    this.title,
    this.colour,
    required this.onPressed,
});
```

Now, for the `colour` property, you won't need to change anything, since `Material.color` can be null. However, since `Text` requires a non-nullable `String`, you'll have to change the way you pass the `title` property:

```
Text(
    title ?? "", // If title is null, use an empty string
    // ...
)
```

or

```
child: title == null // Only build the Text widget if title is not null
    ? null 
    : Text(
          title,
          // ...
      )
```

In depth reading on null safety here: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Answer (score 1):

As said also in the previous anwser:

1. Change the @required => **required**
2. Add **'?'** to potentially nullable variable
3. Add *default* value

In your case maybe I'll use something like this:

```
final String title;
final Color colour;
final VoidCallBack? onPressed;

RoundedButton({
    required this.title,
    this.colour = Colors.blue,
    this.onPressed,
});
```

Because the title can't be null, the colour can be the default one and the onPress can be empty for future implementation of your app.